# will a signed .ipa installed on jailbroken ipad expire?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

I installed a signed ipa file on my jailbreak ipad and see the provision file will expire in  a year. This is a jailbreak device. Will this ipa expire in a year on ipad? Or should I provide another valid provision file after a year?

Comment: this question is not off-topic.  code-signing is a part of programming.

Answer (score 2):

My wild guess that it will expire.

Based on my understanding of jailbreak procedure, one of the thing which jailbreak does is to disabling checking of signature (whether provisioning profiles are signed by Apple or something else). I don't think that they go and circumvent other protection mechanism (why should they care, if they can create provisioning profile which will expire in 100 years).

However, all of these are speculations. And also, it depends on jailbreak itself (different jailbreak applications for different iOS version could disable different protection mechanisms).

Comment: +1 because *I think* this is true.  I've never paid close enough attention, even though I usually jailbreak my phones.  My vague memory says that my development apps do eventually expire, and need to be rebuilt/reinstalled.